# onTouchEvent method in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-gesture

I've tried to implement Common Gestures detection mechanism in particular fragment in my app.

I've implemented all necessary methods onDown, onShowPress etc.
Gesture Detector class has been initalized in onCreateView.

When user performs one of these gestures, app should call convertion method frome ViewModel instance also implemented in this fragment.

Problem is with overriding onTouchEvent.  AndroidStudio sends me error that onTouchEvent doesn't override any method.

How can I solve this issue?

Code here:

Fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment  implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

private SecondViewModel mViewModel;
private GestureDetectorCompat gDetector;
private final float rate = 3.14f;



public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
    return new SecondFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), this);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SecondViewModel.class);




    TextView euroView = getView().findViewById(R.id.inEuro);
    TextView valueView = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Switch mSwitch = getView().findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);


    mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Navigation.findNavController(mSwitch).navigate(R.id.moveToMain);
            }
        }
    });

    final Observer<Float> valueObserver = new Observer<Float>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final Float myValue) {
            valueView.setText(myValue.toString());
        }
    };

    final Observer<Float> euroValueObserver = new Observer<Float>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Float myValue) {
            euroView.setText(myValue.toString());
        }
    };

    mViewModel.getValue().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), valueObserver);
    mViewModel.getEuroV().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), euroValueObserver);
}


@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
        mViewModel.setValue(SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getVal());
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

   mViewModel.convertion();

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    mViewModel.convertion();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    mViewModel.convertion();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    mViewModel.convertion();
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return getActivity().onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

*Soluton with onTouch method*

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SecondViewModel.class);
    secondFrag = getView().findViewById(R.id.ConstraintLayout);
    euroView = getView().findViewById(R.id.inEuro);
    valueView = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mSwitch = getView().findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
    mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Navigation.findNavController(mSwitch).navigate(R.id.moveToMain);
            }
        }
    });
    secondFrag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        GestureDetectorCompat gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent p1) {

                euroView.setText("true");

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent p1) {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent p1) {
                euroView.setText("true");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent p1, MotionEvent p2, float p3, float p4) {
                euroView.setText("true");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent p1) {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent p1, MotionEvent p2, float p3, float p4) {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return false;
            }
        });


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            secondFrag.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

XML files of Host Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2ndFragmentWithViewModel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.456" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inEuro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="MyTextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17000002" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe try onTouch(...)?

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
     return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

Comment: still isn't the case :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "isn't the case". onTouch can't be overridden?

Comment: Yes, "method doesn't override it's method frome superclass"

Comment: Gesture detector does not have a touch event. Anyway, someView.setOnTouchListener has an onTouch.

Comment: What view are you trying to detect gesture on?

Comment: The "view" in this example is whole space occupied by this fragment.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I came up with an solution for this.

For purpose of implementing in particular fragment gesture detection, eg. swipe to right, left etc.  we presumably can't use a GesturDetectorCompat class. As a replacement I found to write my own CommonGestureDetector class.
It reads as follow:

```
  public class OnSwipeListener  implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeListener(Context context){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureListener());
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return  gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends  GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e){return  true;}

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    onSwipeRight();
                } else {
                    onSwipeLeft();
                }
            }
        } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (diffY > 0) {
                onSwipeBottom();
            } else {
                onSwipeTop();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
   }
  public void onSwipeRight() {
     }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }

     }
```

It's source is frome here: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/16543/swipe-detection

This's kind of our own implementation of GestureDetectorCompat, this perfectly fits in Fragments and we still keeping  our project class code "shine-and-clean".

How it looks in my app:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private MainViewModel mViewModel;

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.testView);
   view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeListener(getContext()){
   public void onSwipeTop()
    {
        textView.setText("top");
    }
   public void onSwipeRight()
    {textView.setText("right");}
    public void onSwipeLeft(){textView.setText("left");}
    public void onSwipeBottom(){textView.setText("bottom");}
});
    return view;


}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);


    // TODO: Use the ViewModel
}
```

}

So, as can you see, earlier mentioned class is passed as an argument to the setOnTouchListener in  OnActivityCreated method of our fragment, with minimum coding effort to write it :)

I hope this will help somebody someday :)

Big thanks to @AliEid for his interest in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize your parent view:

```
private FrameLayout parentView;
parentView = getView().findViewById(R.id.parent_view);
```

Then set a touch listener to it:

```
parentView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
                GestureDetectorCompat gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity() , new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent p1) {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent p1) {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent p1) {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent p1, MotionEvent p2, float p3, float p4) {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent p1) {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent p1, MotionEvent p2, float p3, float p4) {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            return false;
                        }
                        
                
            });
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View p1, MotionEvent p2) {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    return false;
                }
                
            
        });
```

XML files of Host Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2ndFragmentWithViewModel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.456" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inEuro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="MyTextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17000002" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

I've implemented this solution in OnActivityCreated method. 
Earlier I initialize my parent View of course. I've also supressed some warnings about PerformClick().

App still doesn't respond to performed gestures :( Where is the problem now? 

I've updated global post with new code. 

Regards

Comment: I just used onLongPress to set a text and change its visibility.

Comment: What happens if you single tap? Maybe another view is overlapping the parent view?

Comment: I'd like to suggest creating a more visible view ( cardview for example) and trying on it. I'm using gestures on a view pager with no such problem for me. Or maybe try initializing your views inside onCreateView and do the stuff when the activity is created.

Comment: With my project I'm using destinations. Therefore I've implemented host layout in Navigation Graph. When user clicks button on 1st screen, hosts layout's replaced by my Fragment. Is it possible that host layout (container) is overlapping that? I've updated code, to show XML files

Comment: my Fragment has been also created using Fragment + View Model option, so it has kind of container for it's content. I've tried using your solution in brand new project with same template (Fragment + View Model),  isn't working :(

Comment: I'm sorry mate I've reached my max knowledge here. I upvoted your quedtion. Hope you get a helping hand.